# AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Crashes only on iPad

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

This line crashes only on iPads. I am using swift 4.2. I am setting up a upc scanner:

```
 func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it or is it just from crash logs? If it's just crash log, what's inside that delegate method? Also, could you try reproducing it to find the exact line?

Answer (score 0):

You were correct. The crash log gave me the line number of the delegate. Turns out it was inside as you suggested, and it just happened that the two iPads had a setting of a flag that didn't exist in the database while all the iPhones for testing didn't try to set that flag. Thanks for looking.